# applyResolversEnhanceMap not adding custom decorators to resolvers?

Tags: typescript, typegraphql

I'm using the `typegraphql-prisma` package and am trying to apply custom decorators to my generated resolvers to no avail. I'm trying to wrap my head around the bottleneck, but can't seem to identify it.

```js
// src/lib/enhance.ts
export const mapped: ResolversEnhanceMap = {
  Like: {
    deleteLike: [RateLimitMiddleware()],
    createLike: [RateLimitMiddleware()],
  },
};
```

```js
// src/lib/middleware.ts
const duration = 60 * 60;
const limit = 1;

export function RateLimitMiddleware() {
  console.log("Middleware is running...");
  // nothing below this line runs
  return createMethodDecorator<Context>(async ({ context, info }, next) => {
    const key = `rate-limit:${info.fieldName}:${context.user.user.id}`;
    console.log(key);
    const total = await redis.incr(key);
    if (total > limit) {
      throw new Error("You are being rate limited.");
    } else if (total === 1) {
      await redis.expire(key, duration);
    }
    return next();
  });
}
```

```js
// src/index.ts
const app = express();
const http = createServer(app);
const schema = await buildSchema({
  resolvers: [...resolvers, AuthResolver, ImageResolver, CardResolver],
  validate: false,
});

applyResolversEnhanceMap(mapped);
// ... more code here
```

It doesn't seem like my RateLimit decorator is being applied at all? Each request goes through triggering any of the `console.log`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem: the answer was to call `applyResolversEnhanceMap` before `buildSchema`.